# How to get "name" from Prefs table when you retrieve a User and related via UserPrefs?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.8 and trying to figure out how to define the relations and get desired data.

I have these three tables.

```
Users: id, name, email
```

```
Preferences: id, name
```

Data example,

```
1, Vegetarian Only
2, Non-Veg Only
3, No preferences
4, Vegan Only
```

```
UserPreferences: id, user_id,preference_id, approved ('Yes', 'No')
```

I want to access all account preferences of a user. These are my Model classes.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function preferences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserPreference', 'user_id', 'id'); 
        //model, foreign_key, local_key
    }
}

class Preference extends Model
{
  // just default empty model class
}

class UserPreference extends Model
{
 // just default empty model class
}
```

When I do

```
$user = User::find(134);
$pref = $user->preferences()->get();
dd($pref);
```

When I do `$pref = $user->preferences()->get();` it includes all the fields from UserPreferences table above but I want to include  `name` as prefName from `preferences` table too.

I am not sure how to do that. Can you please help me define the relations correctly?

**Update**

Basically, `$pref = $user->preferences()->get();` runs a query like 
`SELECT * FROM UserPrefererences WHERE user_id=134`

However, I want to be able to achieve result as from this query -
`SELECT *, pf.name pref_name FROM UserPrefererences upf INNER JOIN Preferences pf ON pf.id = upf.preference_id WHERE upf.user_id=134`

Comment: Do you mean you want extra column from preferences.

Comment: Yes please take a look at my Update above in my question.

Comment: Does the above mean that a user can have the same preference multiple times?

Comment: @apokryfos - No - no duplicate preferences for a user but they can have multiple different preferences. Basically Preferences is a list. An admin can assign one or more preferences from this list to any user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you would define your relationships like that is to allow the same `user_id, preference_id` pair. If you don't need this then you should convert your `user_preferences` table to a pivot table. Here's what you do:

1) Remove the `id` column from `user_preferences`

2) Remove the `UserPreference` class completely

3) Define your relationship like below:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function preferences()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Preference')->withPivot('approved'); 
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$prefs = $user->preferences;
$prefs->first()->name;  //Here it is
$prefs->first()->pivot->approved; //The approved value
```

In case you still want to keep the `UserPreferences` you can do the following:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function preferences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserPreference', 'user_id', 'id'); 
        //model, foreign_key, local_key
    }
}

class UserPreference extends Model
{
       public function preference() {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Preference');
       }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$prefs = $user->preferences()->with('preference')->get();
$prefs->first()->preference->name; //here it is
```

Comment: Thank you - let me try that. Also, can I get all that data in one line to pass one variable to my blade file? E.g. `dd($user)` ... would output `array('id' =>1, "name" => "Joe", "preferences" => array("id" => 4, "user_id" =>1, "prefName" => "Veg Only"))`

Comment: @NoNice I've written a different answer which will work better I think. If anything if you define the `user_preferences` as a pivot table you're avoiding anomalies like the same user having the same preference multiple times like a user could be vegan 3 times (which doesn't make sense I think)

Comment: Yes your original answer worked for me. I was able to define the relation but didn't know how to retrieve the value so `$prefs = $user->preferences()->with('preference')->get();
$prefs->first()->preference->name; ` helped me to understand how to get that. so thank you for that.

Comment: Also, I see your point re using pivot. However, I have an existing non-laravel application using the same database so I won't be able to change the schema. But I am sure I will keep it in mind for future new development. I need to get my head around that first how that works though.

Comment: I think the code might still work even if you don't remove the `id` column. I just mention that so you are then guaranteed you won't get the same `user_id, preference_id` pair in the table since that will need to become your new primary key

Comment: Am I able to define more fields in your point 3 above? There are more fields in this table other than approved.  `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Preference')->withPivot('approved');`  Do I just comma separate fields?

Comment: Great - Just looking at your pivot example, you mentioned to remove UserPrefs class and in User model class `public function preferences() {  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Preference')->withPivot('approved');  }` - you are referencing to App\Preference class - does that mean laravel is making assumption of the pivot table name?

Comment: Yes. You can change that as the 2nd parameter of belongsToMany.